# Generating and Downloading pdf not working in Shopify POS APP

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopify, jspdf, html2canvas

In react shopify admin app, from browser, I can generate and download pdf using html2canvas, jspdf.

My code is like below:

```html
    const result = handleValidation();
    if (result.show === true && result.message != "") {
      setToastData({
        show: true,
        isError: true,
        message: result.message,
      });
      return;
    }
    const capture = document.querySelector(".actual-receipt-create-order");

    const dpi = 300;
    const scale = dpi / 96;

    html2canvas(capture, { scale: scale }).then((canvas) => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("img/png");
      const doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
      const componentWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
      const componentHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
      doc.addImage(imgData, "PNG", 0, 0, componentWidth, componentHeight);
      doc.save("receipt.pdf");
    });
```

```html
                    <div
                      className="actual-receipt-create-order"
                      style={{
                        backgroundColor: "white",
                        padding: "5px",
                        position: "absolute",
                        left: "-9999px",
                        top: "-9999px",
                      }}
                    >
                    body of pdf
                    </div>
```

This works fine in the web app, but when I run the app in shopify POS app, file is not being downloaded. What could be the reason? I also tried with other library like jspdf. But result is same, in POS it doesn't work.

Comment: @KJ Thanks for your response. I tried with removing  left: "-9999px",top: "-9999px" but result was same. Can not download shopify POS app. seems html2canvas/jsPDF not working in shopify POS mobile app...
can you suggest any other library for shopify POS app to generate and download pdf

Comment: @KJ Thanks for your continuous response and support. As per your feedback, inspected  the app using debugging mode

https://www.loom.com/share/8936d93e13f74023ae2b4232a81873e5?sid=4f8523a3-c743-4b57-9fbd-00883a5f5fe8

 
only got a CORS issue for two images which was also given from web app (from browser) and from web app pdf was downloaded. Also this images are not being used in pdf rather used in page component which rendered smoothly in POS app.

Comment: Hello @atk,
I have a same problem, the print dialog does not showing up at all, I just try the following sample code but without success.
 try {
            document.execCommand('print', false, null);
          }
          catch(e) {
            window.print();
          }
Could you please help me?